# I can not navigate through the objects in sql server managemente studio - lock never goes away

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms, locking

Whenever I try to navigate through the objects in sql server management studio object explorer I get the error message

> Lock request time out period exceeded. (Microsoft SQL Server, error:
> 1222).

It is impossible to list columns in tables, show code of views and procedures, etc.

It's a SQL Server 2016.

How to look for the cause of this ?

There is a lot of ETL running on the server, can that be the cause ? How to pinpoint the cause ?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["lock request time out period exceeded" Error When Trying to See DB Hierarchies](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23335/lock-request-time-out-period-exceeded-error-when-trying-to-see-db-hierarchies). It has multiple answers similar to those provided in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [David Browne - Microsoft](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/269442/22336) that you can look at  [sys.dm_tran_locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-locks-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-waiting-tasks-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

You can also see [which table/object the KEY or PAGE or EXTENT locks in the sys.dm_tran_locks belong to](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/245442/22336).

**But** if you want to make your life easier have a look at [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/docs/) or [some alternatives](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/205590/22336) also good.

You can also start [monitoring blocking](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/208352/22336).

Answer (score 2):

Someone's got an open transaction involving the system tables.

Look at [sys.dm_tran_locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-locks-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

While SSMS is waiting you can examine [sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-waiting-tasks-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to see which session it's blocked by.

Comment: The conflicting locks could have come from earlier in a transaction.

Answer (score -1):

You can use DBeaver instead of SSMS.  It doesn't suffer from this issue.

Our organisation has very large legacy apps on SQL Server, but is gradually moving to PostgreSQL on AWS. As a result, I use both SSMS and DBeaver heavily every day. SSMS is great for SQL Server while DBeaver is great for PostgreSQL and passable for SQL Server.

When I encounter the issue described in the question in SSMS, I find DBeaver doesn't get blocked. While there may be a short delay, DBeaver is able to display all objects even when SQL Server is not able to display anything at all. I do not know enough yet about the DBeaver internals to know if it is achieving this by caching.